# How to restore a Complete Database from SQL Server 2012 to SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I want to restore a database

- To : my laptop containing SQL Server 2008 R2
- From: SQL Server 2012 which is on another laptop

and is there a way to restore 2 same databases in SQL Server 2012 with different names, I tried but its showing some `.mdf` kind of error.

Appreciating your helps,

Thanks :)

Comment: you need to use Generate scripts

Comment: Where can i find the option to generate scripts?

Comment: You can't restore new backups to older versions of SQL Server, even if you put the new database in a compatibility mode that matches the older server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

- Right click on your database and select Tasks -> Generate Scripts and Complete Wizard it is simpler

[image: Here You can select data/schema as you want]

- Finally execute this `.sql` file on destination database use Change Database Name in first Line `Use Database`

Comment: Why there is -2 before my question. :(

Comment: @DheerajSharma its called as down vote which will decreases your reputation/points. i will suggest you to do Google on the which question you want to ask on stackoverflow.com. Asking basic questions leads to down votes on stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 2):

You **CANNOT** do this - you cannot attach/detach or backup/restore a database from a **newer version** of SQL Server (2012) down to an **older version** (2008 R2) - the internal file structures are just too different to support backwards compatibility.

You can either get around this problem by

- using the same version of SQL Server on all your machines - then you can easily backup/restore databases between instances
- otherwise you can create the database scripts for both structure (tables, view, stored procedures etc.) and for contents (the actual data contained in the tables) either in SQL Server Management Studio (`Tasks > Generate Scripts`) or using a third-party tool
- or you can use a third-party tool like Red-Gate's [SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) and [SQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-data-compare/) to do "diffing" between your source and target, generate update scripts from those differences, and then execute those scripts on the target platform; this works across different SQL Server versions.